# What are the metal shavings in my bottom bracket from?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I opened up my FSA BB30 bottom bracket to find metal shavings all around. I opened up the bracket to try to find the source of a creaking sound, I’m guessing this is it - but I’m not quite sure what to fix/replace based on the metal shavings.

[image: metal shavings before cleaning]

[image: bottom bracket and bearings after cleaning area]

Comment: First look to see if the bearings are all there.  If not then they probably ate themselves.  But this could be shavings that fell down the seat tube, as someone was trying to make a seat post fit or some such.

Comment: @DanielRHicks thanks! So buy a BB30 bearing removal tool to check out the bearings? Something like this? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00426ENBU/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_ubNtBbDKXZ86Q

Comment: If the bearings are intact then it seems unlikely that they're the source of the shavings.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I think your frame shavings from a drilled out hole is a real good theory. Doesn’t explain my BB creak, but does seem unrelated based on your theory. Probably will pull the bearings anyways to find the creak :)

Comment: In a more conventional cartridge BB setup "creak" is often due to the cones that hold the cartridge in place being loose.  But I have no experience with your setup.  (And, of course, note that "creak" can also be due to a loose crank arm -- a much more critical problem.)

Comment: Metal shavings are obviously chips from a cutting tool. They seem to be the same metal as the frame They actually may have gotten there during frame prep stage of assembly - perhaps from bottom bracket shell or sear tube reaming.

Comment: They're quite large shavings - so not the normal dust-that-used-to-be-a-bearing.   I guess someone was just lazy while installing bottle cage bosses ?

Comment: @dpollitt  You can post your own answer that wraps up all the little bits in comments, and you're encouraged to mark it as accepted too, because that's what worked for you.   Most of the comments are informed guesses, you're the one who can add your experience.

Comment: Does the spindle appear pretty good and still measure 30.00 -/+.02mm-ish? How do the bearings feel?

Comment: Sloppy cleaning at assembly of the bike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- The seat tube or theoretically the head tube was reamed after the bottom bracket was installed, either at the factory or during assembly or service.
- A little deposit of cuttings somehow got lodged in the seat tube or down tube from any of the many manufacturing steps that could create them, perhaps sticking to the inside of the tube with the help of some cutting fluid, and they made it all the way through the process but came loose over time once the bike started being ridden.
- Some kind of simple brain fart, or laziness, or apathy, or some combination thereof on the part of whoever reamed the shell or seattube or assemeble the BB/cranks at the factory.
- One corner case scenario that's theoretically possible with all cartridge bearing bike components is the bearing seizes due to extreme wear, alignment, fit, and/or quality issues (maybe some other factors too) and the spindle, axle, or bearing bore they're supposed to have stationary contact with is now a dynamic contact, which will start wearing away material, in this case from the crank spindle. If something like that did happen here I'd have no idea how the material got lost in such a shaving-like way, but I've seen weirder

It's not necessarily connected to the creak in any way. BB30 is simply prone to creaks.